# Windows guest keyboard shortcut to SSH dbus command to Ubuntu host on KVM

Tags: ssh, kvm

I use the following command with a keyboard shortcut to globally skip to the next song on Spotify:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
```

My Spotify is running on my Ubuntu host.
How do I set up a keyboard shortcut on the Windows guest to SSH this command to the host?

Comment: So you want the event that initially happens on *the host's keyboard* to be passed into the Windows guest, trigger a SSH command there, which will again contact the host OS and skip to the next song? Wouldn't just defining a global shortcut on the host's desktop environment be a more direct way to achieve this? Or do you have a separate USB keyboard that is assigned to be directly controlled by the Windows guest, and you want the shortcut specifically on that keyboard?

Comment: No, I have the shortcut for skipping the song globally on my Ubuntu host, where Spotify is running. But when I am in my Windows guest, I have to first release the guest focus with Ctrl + Alt or hover to the top middle of the screen, to make the shortcut execute on the host. So I would need a shortcut on the Windows guest to send the dbus command to the host via SSH.

Comment: That's one possible solution, yes. Alternatively, you might need the host-level shortcut defined in such a way that it cannot be overridden/captured by the VM, but always takes effect on the host. That might be doable too. Does your keyboard include any multimedia keys or similar? The events for those sometimes take a slightly different processing route than regular keyboard key events, and might be easier to use for the kind of global shortcuts you're looking for.

Comment: "Alternatively, you might need the host-level shortcut defined in such a way that it cannot be overridden/captured by the VM, but always takes effect on the host." - what about the the focus? The focus is either on the vm or on the host, and the switcher is ctrl + alt. So a shortcut that is defined so that it cannot be captured by the VM, can override the focus thing? if yes, could you give an example of code or GUI setting? this is QEMU/virsh/KVM. These are my GUI settings: https://i.imgur.com/BwPTOzi.png